# node webkit prevent access on the same network

Tags: node.js, express, node-webkit

I made a custom application using node webkit and the Express.js.
I run this application on my PC, and all works fine.

How can I prevent someone else from using that application from the same network, so it is working only on the localhost.

For example I run this app on my localhost (192.168.1.1:8000). Now anyone else on the same network can open a browser and go directly to 192.168.1.8000. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `listen`, you can specify an `hostname`, request that does not come from the hostname will be dropped. You can assign 127.0.0.1 for you only to access it.

> *server.listen(port[, hostname][, backlog][, callback])* - Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections on any IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise. A port value of zero will assign a random port.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly you want to block port 8000 on your firewall, it has nothing to do with node webkit..
or you can run your express server on a different port (3000 maybe?)